# What is the exact function of だけ in this sentence?

Tags: sentence, particle-だけ

[image]

The character recently has been having problems at schools. He got called by the teachers and he however denies to them he has been having problems.

Then he talks to a friend and tells him this.

My understanding is akin to "If I get thought/If I become feed up with this, I only need to take a short break".

Then he explains he's used to not going to school or not having friends anyway.

This said, I don't see why he used だけだし here?

Answer (score 1):

I think that rather than the duration of the break,

> 嫌になったら休む**だけ**だし

means "If it gets unpleasant, I **just/only** skip school, taking 休む in the sense of "not attending school/job, to be absent" (see [1. and 4. here](https://jisho.org/search/yasumu)) specifically, rather than "resting" in general.

I feel that だけ here adds the nuance that the speaker means he or she is NOT doing other bad things (such as engaging in a gang, vandalism or whatever) besides skipping school, he or she **only** skips school and that's it.